# What does the compiler error "missing binary operator before token" mean?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I recently got the following error when trying to compile with gcc:

> error: missing binary operator before token "("

Web and SO searches came up with several specific examples of this error, with specific code changes to fix them.   But I found no general description of what condition causes this error to be issued.

When and why does gcc emit this error?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is not a compiler error, it is a preprocessor error. It occurs when the preprocessor encounters invalid syntax while trying to evaluate an expression in a `#if` or `#elif` directive.

One common cause is the `sizeof` operator in an `#if` directive:

For example:

```
  #define NBITS (sizeof(TYPE)*8)
  //later
  #if (NBITS>16)    //ERROR
```

This is an error because [`sizeof` is evaluated by the compiler, not the preprocesor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612322/10396).

Type casts are also not valid preprocessor syntax:

```
  #define ALLBITS ((unsigned int) -1)
  //later
  #if (ALLBITS>0xFFFF)    //ERROR
```

The [rules for what can be in a valid expression are here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If).

Note also that `#if` will evaluate an undefined macro as 0, unless it looks like it takes arguments, in which case you [also get this error](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36453):

So if `THIS` is undefined:

```
#if THIS == 0  //valid, true

#if THIS > 0 //valid, false

#if THIS() == 0  //invalid. ERROR
```

[Typos in your `#if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194411/10396) can also cause this message.

Comment: The error message is indeed misleading, and IMHO, the preprocessor should output a more meaningful one for the errors that actually occur in practice. So, I've just reported a bug in the GCC Bugzilla: [Bug 87351 - misleading error message: missing binary operator before token "("](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87351)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question; it's just explaining preprocessor syntax.

Comment: Um, I wrote both the question and this answer.   The question is "What does this error message mean".  The answer is "it's a preprocesor syntax error in a conditional, and here are some common examples of  syntax that cause it."  

I wrote this because when I tried to search for the cause of this error message, everything I found were specific examples of changes to make it go away, but  no explanation about what the message actually _means_.

Feel free to improve the answer, that's what the edit button is for.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Linux, make sure that you do not have a header named `features.h` inside your project files.
I had one with this name, which resulted in:

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h:25: error: function pointer expected

or

> /usr/include/bits/huge_val.h:26:18: error: missing binary operator before token 
>   "("

That is because some system headers like `huge_val.h` use macros like `__GNUC_PREREQ` that are defined by `/usr/include/features.h` (learn more about this header [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645238/what-is-the-purpose-of-features-h-header)).

In my case I first saw this error when I started to use gcc's -I option which suddenly made gcc select my project include directory *before* the default system include directories.

Comment: Got a similar issue with a `features` header in Xilinx Vivado HLS C synthesis because of file `<path-to>/Vivado/2017.4/lnx64/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/include-fixed/features.h:339:0`

Answer (score 1):

You get this error sometimes if you have `-fno-operator-names` in your compiler flags. I suffered from the exact error while building `json` and this solved it.

Answer (score -7):

check the direct. no space,no special
exp:
add_subdirectory(Main)->add_subdirectory(main)

Comment: You can check your folder's name.  I had solved the problem by this way.

Comment: Then I would advise that you a) add more context and explain how you're using CMake, b) improve the grammar and formatting of your answer for clarity.

Comment: Refer to:https://www.crifan.com/cygwin_buildroot_xscale_make_bin_sh_c_line_0_syntax_error_near_unexpected_token_left_parenthesis/