# Preprocessor Errors Compiling Chrono_io

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, c++-chrono

Recently pulled some code to a new system, and I'm having some trouble compiling chrono_io and ratio_io.

I'm unsure what to change, since the errors [appear to affect the preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean).

It seems like it must be a cross-platform compatibility issue for which the code doesn't account.

Any ideas how I can resolve these preprocessor and compiler errors?

```
In file included from Test.cc:12:0:
chrono_io:221:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:789:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:821:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:833:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:845:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:858:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
chrono_io:885:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
                  ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:36:1: error: ‘_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 _LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
 ^
ratio_io:46:1: error: ‘basic_string’ does not name a type
 basic_string<_CharT>
 ^
ratio_io:58:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<atto, char>
        ^
ratio_io:58:21: error: ‘atto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<atto, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:58:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:513:47: note:   ‘std::atto’
   typedef ratio<1,       1000000000000000000> atto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:59:1: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘ratio_string’
 {
 ^
ratio_io:60:12: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
     static string symbol() {return string(1, 'a');}
            ^
ratio_io:61:12: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
     static string prefix()  {return string("atto");}
            ^
ratio_io:83:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<atto, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:83:21: error: ‘atto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<atto, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:83:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:513:47: note:   ‘std::atto’
   typedef ratio<1,       1000000000000000000> atto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:83:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<atto, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:92:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<femto, char>
        ^
ratio_io:92:21: error: ‘femto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<femto, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:92:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:514:47: note:   ‘std::femto’
   typedef ratio<1,          1000000000000000> femto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:92:32: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<femto, char>
                                ^
ratio_io:117:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<femto, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:117:21: error: ‘femto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<femto, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:117:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:514:47: note:   ‘std::femto’
   typedef ratio<1,          1000000000000000> femto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:117:35: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<femto, wchar_t>
                                   ^
ratio_io:126:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<pico, char>
        ^
ratio_io:126:21: error: ‘pico’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<pico, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:126:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:515:47: note:   ‘std::pico’
   typedef ratio<1,             1000000000000> pico;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:126:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<pico, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:151:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<pico, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:151:21: error: ‘pico’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<pico, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:151:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:515:47: note:   ‘std::pico’
   typedef ratio<1,             1000000000000> pico;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:151:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<pico, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:160:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<nano, char>
        ^
ratio_io:160:21: error: ‘nano’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<nano, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:160:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:516:47: note:   ‘std::nano’
   typedef ratio<1,                1000000000> nano;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:160:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<nano, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:185:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<nano, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:185:21: error: ‘nano’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<nano, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:185:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:516:47: note:   ‘std::nano’
   typedef ratio<1,                1000000000> nano;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:185:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<nano, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:194:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<micro, char>
        ^
ratio_io:194:21: error: ‘micro’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<micro, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:194:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:517:47: note:   ‘std::micro’
   typedef ratio<1,                   1000000> micro;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:194:32: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<micro, char>
                                ^
ratio_io:219:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<micro, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:219:21: error: ‘micro’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<micro, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:219:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:517:47: note:   ‘std::micro’
   typedef ratio<1,                   1000000> micro;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:219:35: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<micro, wchar_t>
                                   ^
ratio_io:228:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<milli, char>
        ^
ratio_io:228:21: error: ‘milli’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<milli, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:228:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:518:47: note:   ‘std::milli’
   typedef ratio<1,                      1000> milli;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:228:32: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<milli, char>
                                ^
ratio_io:253:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<milli, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:253:21: error: ‘milli’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<milli, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:253:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:518:47: note:   ‘std::milli’
   typedef ratio<1,                      1000> milli;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:253:35: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<milli, wchar_t>
                                   ^
ratio_io:262:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<centi, char>
        ^
ratio_io:262:21: error: ‘centi’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<centi, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:262:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:519:47: note:   ‘std::centi’
   typedef ratio<1,                       100> centi;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:262:32: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<centi, char>
                                ^
ratio_io:287:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<centi, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:287:21: error: ‘centi’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<centi, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:287:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:519:47: note:   ‘std::centi’
   typedef ratio<1,                       100> centi;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:287:35: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<centi, wchar_t>
                                   ^
ratio_io:296:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<deci, char>
        ^
ratio_io:296:21: error: ‘deci’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<deci, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:296:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:520:47: note:   ‘std::deci’
   typedef ratio<1,                        10> deci;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:296:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<deci, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:321:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<deci, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:321:21: error: ‘deci’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<deci, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:321:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:520:47: note:   ‘std::deci’
   typedef ratio<1,                        10> deci;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:321:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<deci, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:330:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<deca, char>
        ^
ratio_io:330:21: error: ‘deca’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<deca, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:330:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:521:47: note:   ‘std::deca’
   typedef ratio<                       10, 1> deca;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:330:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<deca, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:355:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<deca, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:355:21: error: ‘deca’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<deca, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:355:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:521:47: note:   ‘std::deca’
   typedef ratio<                       10, 1> deca;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:355:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<deca, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:364:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<hecto, char>
        ^
ratio_io:364:21: error: ‘hecto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<hecto, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:364:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:522:47: note:   ‘std::hecto’
   typedef ratio<                      100, 1> hecto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:364:32: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<hecto, char>
                                ^
ratio_io:389:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<hecto, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:389:21: error: ‘hecto’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<hecto, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:389:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:522:47: note:   ‘std::hecto’
   typedef ratio<                      100, 1> hecto;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:389:35: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<hecto, wchar_t>
                                   ^
ratio_io:398:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<kilo, char>
        ^
ratio_io:398:21: error: ‘kilo’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<kilo, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:398:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:523:47: note:   ‘std::kilo’
   typedef ratio<                     1000, 1> kilo;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:398:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<kilo, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:423:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<kilo, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:423:21: error: ‘kilo’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<kilo, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:423:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:523:47: note:   ‘std::kilo’
   typedef ratio<                     1000, 1> kilo;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:423:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<kilo, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:432:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<mega, char>
        ^
ratio_io:432:21: error: ‘mega’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<mega, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:432:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:524:47: note:   ‘std::mega’
   typedef ratio<                  1000000, 1> mega;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:432:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<mega, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:457:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<mega, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:457:21: error: ‘mega’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<mega, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:457:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:524:47: note:   ‘std::mega’
   typedef ratio<                  1000000, 1> mega;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:457:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<mega, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:466:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<giga, char>
        ^
ratio_io:466:21: error: ‘giga’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<giga, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:466:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:525:47: note:   ‘std::giga’
   typedef ratio<               1000000000, 1> giga;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:466:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<giga, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:491:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<giga, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:491:21: error: ‘giga’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<giga, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:491:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:525:47: note:   ‘std::giga’
   typedef ratio<               1000000000, 1> giga;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:491:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<giga, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:500:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<tera, char>
        ^
ratio_io:500:21: error: ‘tera’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<tera, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:500:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:526:47: note:   ‘std::tera’
   typedef ratio<            1000000000000, 1> tera;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:500:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<tera, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:525:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<tera, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:525:21: error: ‘tera’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<tera, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:525:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:526:47: note:   ‘std::tera’
   typedef ratio<            1000000000000, 1> tera;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:525:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<tera, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:534:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<peta, char>
        ^
ratio_io:534:21: error: ‘peta’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<peta, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:534:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:527:47: note:   ‘std::peta’
   typedef ratio<         1000000000000000, 1> peta;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:534:31: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<peta, char>
                               ^
ratio_io:559:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<peta, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:559:21: error: ‘peta’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<peta, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:559:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:527:47: note:   ‘std::peta’
   typedef ratio<         1000000000000000, 1> peta;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:559:34: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<peta, wchar_t>
                                  ^
ratio_io:568:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<exa, char>
        ^
ratio_io:568:21: error: ‘exa’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<exa, char>
                     ^
ratio_io:568:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:528:47: note:   ‘std::exa’
   typedef ratio<      1000000000000000000, 1> exa;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:568:30: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<exa, char>
                              ^
ratio_io:593:8: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a class template
 struct ratio_string<exa, wchar_t>
        ^
ratio_io:593:21: error: ‘exa’ was not declared in this scope
 struct ratio_string<exa, wchar_t>
                     ^
ratio_io:593:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/chrono:38:0,
                 from Test.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ratio:528:47: note:   ‘std::exa’
   typedef ratio<      1000000000000000000, 1> exa;
                                               ^
In file included from chrono_io:139:0,
                 from Test.cc:12:
ratio_io:593:33: error: ‘ratio_string’ is not a template type
 struct ratio_string<exa, wchar_t>
                                 ^
ratio_io:599:1: error: ‘_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 _LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
 ^
In file included from Test.cc:12:0:
chrono_io:1164:1: error: ‘_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 _LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
 ^
Test.cc: In function ‘void RealDataTest()’:
Test.cc:167:12: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
  std::cout << "Time for n->mostRecent: " << (Clock::now() - start) << std::endl;
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39:0,
                 from Nearby.cc:9,
                 from Test.cc:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
Test.cc:185:12: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
  std::cout << "Time for n->deletePost: " << (Clock::now() - start) << std::endl;
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39:0,
                 from Nearby.cc:9,
                 from Test.cc:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? The first errors suggests that the preprocessor doesn't understand `__has_feature`, which after a quick search seems to be Clang-specific? (Maybe gcc supports it as well?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played with this code in several years.  It is using:

```
#if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)
          __seconds_(std::move(__seconds)),
...
```

to check if the compiler supports rvalue references (C++11 move semantics).  My recommendation is to assume that you have C++11 (since you have to have `<chrono>` and just remove the `__has_feature` and the `#else` branch.

If for some reason you have to support a compiler which doesn't have rvalue references you can:

```
#define __has_feature(x) 0
```

and this will select the `#else` branch everywhere.

`__has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)` is a clang extension.

**Update**

Update to this library.

https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html

It has been simplified to only streaming durations.