# Error while including the jsoncpp lib

Tags: c++, makefile, jsoncpp

I am trying to parse JSON with C++. My Makefile looks as follows:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/home/ting/Temp/code/jsoncpp/libs/linux-gcc-5.4.0/ ./jsoncpp/libs/linux-gcc-5.4.0/libjson.a ./jsoncpp/libs/linux-gcc-5.4.0/libjson.so
INC = -I/home/ting/Temp/code/jsoncpp/include/json

CC=g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11


main: main.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(INC) $^ ${CFLAGS}
```

When I simply `#include "json.h"`, the compiler gives me bunches of errors. I just picked some of them:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: 
missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:44:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/fstream:38,
             from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/wchar.h:74:43: error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

It does not look like the libs have any error. But this problem only appears when I link to the `jsoncpp` lib and add its include dir in the Makefile.

I am so confused; what happened?

Comment: If you want help with your code, post it. For all we know, you're not closing a namespace somewhere, or any other number of syntactical errors that can cascade to the seemingly meaningless fragment of error you posted.

Comment: In general, choosing “some” of the errors isn’t that useful, because a lot of errors can cause other errors in seemingly unrelated parts of the code. Instead, you should pick the *first* error, which has a much better chance of being the actual cause.

Comment: @underscore_d hi. code is pretty simple. I just included the header. #include "json.h". Then I had over several pages error. This is also the reason why I stated "some errors", cause I cannot understand what GCC wanted to say.

Comment: @DanielH Hi. What I posted is actually the first error, cause I got erros over pages and I cannot understand what GCC wanted to say. So I picked the words "some"

Comment: side note: It's more idiomatic to `#include` system headers with `<brackets>`, rather than `"quotes"`. This at least makes your intent clearer and easier to tell between local vs system headers, and it can also alter the search order (though I don't think that's precisely defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsoncpp includes have to be like this:

```
#include <json/json.h>
```

and your include path have to end at *include* dir, this way:

```
INC = -I/home/ting/Temp/code/jsoncpp/include
```

If you omit the json dir from the include, and add it in your INC variable, the compiler will end up picking a **features.h** header *from the json directory*, instead of the required **features.h** of *glibc*, which yields errors like the one you posted (note that features.h in glibc defines that *__GLIBC_PREREQ* macro).

Comment: Hi. My include pach is actually #include"json.h"

Comment: Edit it into #include <json/json.h>, then remove the final json directory from INC and everything should be ok.

Comment: Done. Thought I eventually switched to another json lib. But I still like the explanation.

Comment: This is the undefined macro problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338386/10396)