# Difference between two unsigned long representations

Tags: c

What is the difference between using literal suffix on a constant:

`#define MY_LONG  0x1UL`

and casting a constant:

`#define MY_LONG  (unsigned long)0x1`

When will you choose the former and when will you choose the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no practical difference, these are 100% equivalent.

The only formal difference is that `UL` is part of the integer constant, while the cast could be put in front of any expression, including a run-time evaluated expression.

The main reason for UL is to enforce a type of a integer constant, where it matters. It is often more readable than a cast. Example: `1UL << n` versus `(unsigned long)1 << n`.

Casts on the other hand, have a wider use, as they cannot only be used to force a type at compile-time, but also to trigger a type conversion in run-time.

Comment: So is there a reason to have them both in C language?

Comment: @user2162550: Yes, Lundin indicates that; casting is more of a run-time thing; very informally speaking.

Comment: @user2162550 I added a bit of an explanation to the answer. Basically you are asking why you must have a screwdriver and hammer in your tool box, when you can hammer down a screw with the hammer. The result isn't pretty and potentially something can break if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the difference between using literal suffix on a constant: ... and casting a constant:?

1. It depends on use.

Let us try using the 2 defines as pre-processor steering.  Pre-processor math does not understand various type widths. As part of the token processing:

> For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` ... C11dr §6.10.1 4

```
#define MY_LONG1  0x123456789UL
#define MY_LONG2  (unsigned long)0x123456789

int main(void) {
#if MY_LONG1 == 0x123456789u
  puts("MY_LONG1 == 0x123456789u");
#endif
#if MY_LONG2 == 0x123456789u
  puts("MY_LONG2 == 0x123456789u");
#endif
}
```

`#if MY_LONG2 == 0x123456789u` result in a [compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21338385/2410359).

```
error: missing binary operator before token "long"
 #define MY_LONG2  (unsigned long)0x123456789
```

Note: the `L` serves no purpose with pre-processing.
Note: the `U` does serve a purpose with pre-processing.

2. Otherwise it depends on the value of the constant.

With a value of 1, no difference.

Yet if the value exceeds `ULONG_MAX`, (example: 32-bit), the below is `unsigned long long`.  The `U` insures some *unsigned* type, the `L` insures *at least* `long`.

```
#define MY_LONG  0x123456789UL
```

A cast can change the value.  In this case below, the value becomes 0x23456789 and type `unsigned long`

```
#define MY_LONG  (unsigned long)0x123456789
```

---

> When will you choose the former and when will you choose the latter?

The `L` nudges the type to be at least `long`, the cast enforces the type of `long`.

Use `L` when `MY_LONG` should be at least `long` or the value is small, within the  of *minimal* range of `long` [-2147483647 ... 2147483647]

Do not use the cast if the macro may be used with pre-processing.

Otherwise use the cast `(long)` to enforce a `long`.  IMO, this is rarely the goal.  An exception would be if the constant must be `unsigned long` regardless of it value.

```
// Works well if unsigned long is 64-bit or less
#define MY_ULONG_EVERY_OTHER_BIT  ((unsigned long) 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAu)
```

---

Note: in general, I avoid using `L` in constants and let the implementation determine the type.

The below will be the narrowest type that fits in `unsigned, unsigned long , unsigned long long`.  Appending an `L`  would fit to the narrowest    `unsigned long, unsigned long long`.

```
#define MY_BIGU  0x123456789u
```

---

There is a subtle problem with OP's define.

```
#define MY_LONG  (unsigned long)0x1
```

It should have been the below to insure tight bonding.

```
#define MY_LONG  ((unsigned long)0x1)
```

Only a few operators have higher precedence that could mess up code. Pathological e.g.: `MY_LONG[a]` would be `(unsigned long)(0x1[a])` and not `((unsigned long)0x1)[a]`, yet still good practice to enclose macros with a `()` unless there is zero chance of evaluation  problems.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference. Both are compile time evaluable constant expressions of the same value and type, although you might be wise to write the second version as `((unsigned long)0x1)`.

Personally I'd choose the first one as it's clearer; in my mind at least, a cast is a *run-time* operator, not a *compile-time* one.

Comment: If there is no difference, why do we have them both?

Comment: @user2162550: Because C is flexible. Two different constructs converge to the same thing in certain instances, such as the above. You could levy similar criticism at the `for` loop and even the `switch` block.

Comment: @Bathsheba "You could levy similar criticism at the for loop and even the switch block." Yes!! `goto` ftw! `;-p`

Comment: Please note that chux's answer shows that *there is* a difference.

Comment: @Bob__ Only in the *usage*. But I've made a change here too, Chux's answer is the best one here so far in my opinion. I'm about to upvote it. Thanks for pinging me.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference between the two: they both are constant expressions with a value of `1` and type `unsigned long`.

One notable difference is you can use `0x1UL` as part of a preprocessor test expression, but you cannot use `(unsigned long)1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0x1UL
int main() {
    return 0;
}
#else
#error 0x1UL should be true
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is a way to tell between them, but you really have to try pretty hard:

```
char a [10];
printf( "size is %zu\n", sizeof(MY_LONG [a]) );
```

In the above example, the literal (`0x1UL`) version will have the array take the `unsigned long` literal as an index, yielding `1` because it is `sizeof(char)`. The cast version will have the array taking a `int` literal as an index, then casting the resulting char to `unsigned long` before passing it to `sizeof()`. `sizeof(unsigned long)` is typically `8`.

This is because the indexing operator `[]` outranks the casting operator `()`.