# ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("ragg")
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ragg_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 420401 bytes (410 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 410 KB


Welcome at Tue Aug 17 23:24:09 2021
Library path: /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/R/library

Repositories set.
R_MAX_NUM_DLLS set to 1000.
* installing *source* package ‘ragg’ ...
** package ‘ragg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng16 -lm -lz -lm -lz -ltiff -lwebp -lzstd -llzma -ljbig -ljpeg -lz -lm
-----------------------------[ ANTICONF ]-------------------------------
Configuration failed to find one of freetype2 libpng libtiff-4. Try installing:
 * deb: libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: freetype-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libfreetype_dev libpng16_dev libtiff_dev libjpeg_dev (Solaris)
If freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a freetype2 libpng libtiff-4.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
In file included from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/features.h:361,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/limits.h:27,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/pngconf.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/png.h:339,
                 from <stdin>:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:492:49: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  492 | #if __GNUC_PREREQ (4,8) || __glibc_clang_prereq (3,5)
      |                                                 ^
In file included from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:932,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/pngconf.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/png.h:339,
                 from <stdin>:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:228:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  228 | #if __GLIBC_USE (DEPRECATED_GETS)
      |                 ^
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/R/library/ragg’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpL1ZZnL/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("ragg") :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
```

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language en_GB:en                    
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Stockholm            
#>  date     2021-08-17
```

This issue happens in a conda environment. The suggested linux libraries are installed (see below, run in the same conda env).

```
sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg-dev is already the newest version (8c-2ubuntu8).
libpng-dev is already the newest version (1.6.37-2).
libfreetype6-dev is already the newest version (2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1).
libtiff5-dev is already the newest version (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 26 not to upgrade.
```

`ragg` installation outside the conda env works fine. My guess is that when installing from the conda env, it doesn't find the path to something. Any tips?

Comment: I never mix conda and 'standard' installations on Ubuntu as I am perfectly happy with what Ubuntu gives me -- including the more than 5000 CRAN binaries via the PPA.  So while your mileage may vary, maybe just say no to conda?  Or else ... ask the conda folks.

Comment: If you are using conda, try something like `conda install -c conda-forge r-ragg` (as seen here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-ragg)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
The standard install was only for testing. I use the conda installations for work, to keep environments separate (R versions & packages) for each project.
The conda installation of r-ragg worked. I think ragg could have been installed directly from CRAN by somehow modifying `install.packages()` arguments `configure.args` or `configure.vars`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like something connected to [this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53566303). I encountered the same issue when was trying to install "ragg" package inside my conda env, and the suggested fix in the log (mentioned by [@BlackBear answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74535965/5005169)) is not the real cause of the issue, the issue's cause is showed below in the log:

```
    -------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
In file included from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/features.h:361,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/limits.h:27,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/pngconf.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/png.h:339,
                 from <stdin>:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:492:49: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  492 | #if __GNUC_PREREQ (4,8) || __glibc_clang_prereq (3,5)
      |                                                 ^
In file included from /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/r-4.1/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:932,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/pngconf.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/libpng16/png.h:339,
                 from <stdin>:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:228:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  228 | #if __GLIBC_USE (DEPRECATED_GETS)
      |                 ^
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And it is maybe somehow connected to macros definition confusing. I'm not a big specialist in glibc and other things, for me the suggestion from the @MrFlick in comments to the question to install package directly via conda worked (`mamba install -c conda-forge r-ragg`)

Answer (score 14):

I saw the same error. The fix is to install pkg-config to the conda environment:

conda install -c conda-forge pkg-config

Somehow it seems that R c compiler under conda environment can not call system pkg-config correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is in the log:

```
Configuration failed to find one of freetype2 libpng libtiff-4. Try installing:
 * deb: libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: freetype-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libfreetype_dev libpng16_dev libtiff_dev libjpeg_dev (Solaris)
```

Install those packages and try again.