# Installation of tidyverse using pak fails for me on RedHat 9

Tags: r, tidyverse, pak

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31) -- "Eye Holes"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

What caused `pak::pkg_install("tidyverse")` to fail is the installation of ragg with error

```
> ✖ Failed to build ragg 1.2.7                                            
> Error:                                                                  
> ! error in pak subprocess
> Caused by error in `stop_task_build(state, worker)`:
> ! Failed to build source package ragg.
```

.Last.error

```
> <callr_error/rlib_error_3_0/rlib_error/error>
> Error: 
> ! error in pak subprocess
> Caused by error in `stop_task_build(state, worker)`:
> ! Failed to build source package ragg.
> ---
> Backtrace:
> 1. pak::pkg_install("tidyverse")
> 2. pak:::remote(function(...) get("pkg_install_do_plan", asNamespace("pak"))(...), …
> 3. err$throw(res$error)
> ---
> Subprocess backtrace:
>  1. base::withCallingHandlers(cli_message = function(msg) { …
>  2. get("pkg_install_do_plan", asNamespace("pak"))(...)
>  3. proposal$install()
>  4. pkgdepends::install_package_plan(plan, lib = private$library, num_workers = nw, …
>  5. base::withCallingHandlers({ …
>  6. pkgdepends:::handle_events(state, events)
>  7. pkgdepends:::handle_event(state, i)
>  8. pkgdepends:::stop_task(state, worker)
>  9. pkgdepends:::stop_task_build(state, worker)
> 10. base::throw(pkg_error("Failed to build source package {.pkg {pkg}}.", …
> 11. | base::signalCondition(cond)
> 12. global (function (e) …
```

Comment: If you're using conda, there's a chance `conda install -c conda-forge r-ragg` will work (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824450/error-configuration-failed-for-package-ragg)