# Linphone-sdk desktop build failed: error: missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: c, cmake, gnu, ninja, linphone-sdk

I followed the guide in the page [linphone-sdk](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/) and also run these with the MSYS2 MSYS command in Windows 10:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-cmake
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-ninja
pacman -S p7zip
```

My PATH variable contains these:

```
...C:\msys64;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\lib\p7zip;...
```

Then I run the configuration command:

```
cmake -DENABLE_AAUDIO=OFF -DENABLE_ADVANCED_IM=NO -DENABLE_AMRNB=OFF -DENABLE_AMRWB=OFF -DENABLE_ASSETS=NO -DENABLE_BV16=NO -DENABLE_CAMERA2=OFF -DENABLE_CODEC2=OFF -DENABLE_CSHARP_WRAPPER=OFF -DENABLE_CXX_WRAPPER=NO -DENABLE_DB_STORAGE=NO -DENABLE_DEBUG_LOGS=YES -DENABLE_DOC=OFF -DENABLE_EMBEDDED_OPENH264=OFF -DENABLE_FFMPEG=OFF -DENABLE_G726=OFF -DENABLE_G729=OFF -DENABLE_G729B_CNG=OFF -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=NO -DENABLE_GSM=NO -DENABLE_GTK_UI=OFF -DENABLE_H263=OFF -DENABLE_H263P=OFF -DENABLE_ILBC=OFF -DENABLE_ISAC=OFF -DENABLE_JAVA_WRAPPER=OFF -DENABLE_JAZZY_DOC=OFF -DENABLE_JPEG=NO -DENABLE_LIME=OFF -DENABLE_LIME_X3DH=NO -DENABLE_MBEDTLS=YES -DENABLE_MDNS=OFF -DENABLE_MKV=NO -DENABLE_MPEG4=OFF -DENABLE_NLS=OFF -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=OFF -DENABLE_OPENH264=OFF -DENABLE_OPUS=NO -DENABLE_PCAP=OFF -DENABLE_POLARSSL=OFF -DENABLE_QRCODE=OFF -DENABLE_RTP_MAP_ALWAYS_IN_SDP=OFF -DENABLE_SILK=OFF -DENABLE_SOCI_MYSQL=OFF -DENABLE_SPEEX=YES -DENABLE_SQLITE=YES -DENABLE_SRTP=NO -DENABLE_SWIFT_WRAPPER=OFF -DENABLE_TOOLS=NO -DENABLE_TUNNEL=OFF -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=NO -DENABLE_UNMAINTAINED=OFF -DENABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=OFF -DENABLE_V4L=OFF -DENABLE_VCARD=NO -DENABLE_VIDEO=NO -DENABLE_VPX=OFF -DENABLE_WASAPI=ON -DENABLE_WEBRTC_AEC=YES -DENABLE_WEBRTC_AECM=YES -DENABLE_WEBRTC_VAD=OFF -DENABLE_X264=OFF -DENABLE_XML2=NO -DENABLE_ZLIB=NO -DENABLE_ZRTP=NO -DENABLE_ZRTP=OFF ..
```

and then the build command:

```
cmake --build .
```

I got following build errors (contains from the build log the parts where are the word "failed"):

```
...
[6/10] Forcing build for 'desktop'
[7/10] Performing build step for 'sdk'
FAILED: sdk-prefix/src/sdk-stamp/sdk-build C:/e/linphone-sdk/build/sdk-prefix/src/sdk-stamp/sdk-build 
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\e\linphone-sdk\build\desktop && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cmake.exe --build . && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cmake.exe -E touch C:/e/linphone-sdk/build/sdk-prefix/src/sdk-stamp/sdk-build"
[1/128] Creating directories for 'EP_speex'
[2/128] Creating directories for 'EP_jsoncpp'
...
[29/128] Forcing build for 'EP_jsoncpp'
[30/128] Performing build step for 'EP_mbedtls'
FAILED: C:/e/linphone-sdk/build/WORK/desktop/Stamp/EP_mbedtls/EP_mbedtls-build 
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\e\linphone-sdk\build\WORK\desktop\Build\mbedtls && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cmake.exe --build . && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cmake.exe -E touch C:/e/linphone-sdk/build/WORK/desktop//Stamp/EP_mbedtls/EP_mbedtls-build"
[1/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedx509.dir/pkcs11.c.obj
[2/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedx509.dir/certs.c.obj
...
[63/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/pkcs5.c.obj
[64/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/entropy_poll.c.obj
FAILED: library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/entropy_poll.c.obj 
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\cc.exe -Dmbedcrypto_EXPORTS -IC:/e/linphone-sdk/external/mbedtls/include -IC:/e/linphone-sdk/external/mbedtls/library -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wvla -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Wformat-signedness -Werror -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS -w -MD -MT library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/entropy_poll.c.obj -MF library\CMakeFiles\mbedcrypto.dir\entropy_poll.c.obj.d -o library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/entropy_poll.c.obj -c C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/mbedtls/library/entropy_poll.c
C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/mbedtls/library/entropy_poll.c:59:101: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   59 | #if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION) && defined (WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP) && WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP)
      |                                                                                                     ^
[65/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/version.c.obj
[66/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/threading.c.obj
[67/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/ecp.c.obj
[68/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/platform.c.obj
[69/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/sha256.c.obj
[70/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/pkwrite.c.obj
[71/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/sha512.c.obj
[72/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/sha1.c.obj
[73/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/poly1305.c.obj
[74/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/pkparse.c.obj
[75/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/rsa.c.obj
[76/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/timing.c.obj
[77/89] Building C object library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/psa_crypto.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[31/128] Performing install step for 'EP_openldap'
[32/128] Performing configure step for 'EP_speex'
...
-- Performing Test VAR_ARRAYS - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_ALLOCA
-- Performing Test HAS_ALLOCA - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_SSE
-- Performing Test HAS_SSE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test HAS_VISIBILITY - Success
...
C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp:756:34: warning: 'Reader' is deprecated: Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  756 | Reader::Char Reader::getNextChar() {
      |                                  ^
In file included from C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp:10:
C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/include/json/reader.h:37:63: note: declared here
   37 |     "Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.") JSON_API Reader {
      |                                                               ^~~~~~
C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp:810:21: warning: 'Reader' is deprecated: Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  810 | std::vector<Reader::StructuredError> Reader::getStructuredErrors() const {
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp:10:
C:/e/linphone-sdk/external/jsoncpp/include/json/reader.h:37:63: note: declared here
   37 |     "Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.") JSON_API Reader {
      |                                                               ^~~~~~
[10/11] Linking CXX static library lib\libjsoncpp.a
[11/11] Linking CXX shared library bin\libjsoncpp.dll
[34/128] Performing build step for 'EP_sqlite3'
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/sqlite3.dir/sqlite3.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C shared library libsqlite3.dll
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It seems that the real error is this:

[image: error: missing binary operator before token "("]

I'm not sure what is the cause of the error message:

```
error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

Here [What does the compiler error "missing binary operator before token" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean) is some definition about the error, but I'm not sure why the error happens. Does it happen only in the specific environment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I configured my environment according to the https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/ page and used the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 the build seems to go through.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).