# PTHREAD_STACK_MIN causing problem in compiling buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot, microchip

i'm trying to compile a Linux image with sysroot and cross-compiler by buildroot for ATSAMA5D27-WLSOM1 evaluation kit by Microchip.
I'm on a virtual machine (VBox) with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
I'm following this guide: https://microchip.wikidot.com/32mpu:egt-prepare#prepHost
I arrived at point 6, but there are some errors in compilation, the one I can't solve is the following one:

```
   In file included from /home/ubuntu4sam/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/10.3.0/include-fixed/pthread.h:42,
                 from work_thread.c:13:
work_thread.c:45:58: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   45 | #if defined (PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) && THREAD_MINSTACKSIZE < PTHREAD_STACK_MIN
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to comment the second condition (THREAD_MINSTACKSIZE < PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) and the error becomes:

```
work_thread.c:45:58: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   45 | #if defined (PTHREAD_STACK_MIN)
```

so the problem must be PTHREAD_STACK_MIN. I hope someone else has worked on Microchip boards.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's a preprocessor error; have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338385/what-does-the-compiler-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-mean) thread.  Can you locate and paste the definition of 'PTHREAD_STACK_MIN' into your question or here in the comments?